# Making "inout" function with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

So i'm migrating a project to Swift 5.1 from objective C. Currently, i have a piece of code, which is the following, already in Swift:

```
    func getStoryDetail(with jsonDict: inout [AnyHashable : Any] , success: NetworkManagerSuccess, failure: NetworkManagerFailure) {

        manager?.post("CUSTOM_API_URL", parameters: jsonDict, progress: nil, success: { operation, responseObject in
            if let responseObject = responseObject {
                print("\(responseObject)")
            }
            //success(responseObject)
        }, failure: { operation, error in

                print("\n\nFailed: Error:\n: \(error)")

            //failure(error)
        })
    }
```

And i'm calling this function in Objective C using the Bridge Header:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber] forKey:kPage];
[jsonDict setValue:storyId forKey:kStoryId];

[[StoryService sharedManager] getStoryDetailWith:jsonDict success:^(id responseObject) {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        isLoading = NO;

        if (![responseObject isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            NSString *responseCode = [responseObject objectForKey:@"ResponseCode"];

            if ([responseCode isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                NSMutableArray *arrNewList = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Result"] mutableCopy];
                if (arrNewList.count == 0) {
                    shouldLoadMore = NO;
                } else {
                    if (pageNumber == 1) {
                        arrayStoryConversation = arrNewList;
                        [self loadNextMessage];
                    } else {
                        [arrayStoryConversation addObjectsFromArray:arrNewList];
                    }
                    pageNumber++;
                    shouldLoadMore = YES;
                    if (arrayStoryConversation.count == [[responseObject objectForKey:@"TotalCount"] intValue]) {
                        shouldLoadMore = NO;
                    }
                }
                if ([responseObject objectForKey:@"Next_result"]) {
                    _nextStory = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Next_result"];
                }
            } else {
                shouldLoadMore = NO;
                [self showALertViewWithTitle:@"Oops!" withText:[responseObject objectForKey:@"ResponseMessage"] andButtonText:@"Ok"];
            }

            intTotalLikes = [[responseObject objectForKey:klike_count] intValue];
            intTotalComment = [[responseObject objectForKey:kcomment_Count] intValue];
            if ([[responseObject objectForKey:kUserlike] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                isFavStory = YES;
            } else {
                isFavStory = NO;
            }
            [self.tblStory reloadData];

        } else {
            [self getConversationList:showLoader];
        }

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        isLoading = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        NSString *message;
        BOOL showCancelButton = YES;
        if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
            showCancelButton = NO;
            message = @"Request time out.";
        } else if (error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet || error.code == NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost || error.code == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost) {
            showCancelButton = NO;
            message = @"Internet connection goes down.";
        } else if (error.code == NSURLErrorBadServerResponse) {
            showCancelButton = YES;
            message = @"Any technical problem on server side.";
        } else {
            showCancelButton = NO;
            message = @"Request couldn't be completed.";
        }

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Failed" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *actionTryAgain = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Try Again" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            [self getConversationList:showLoader];
        }];
        [alertController addAction:actionTryAgain];

        if (showCancelButton) {
            UIAlertAction *actionCancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            }];
            [alertController addAction:actionCancel];
        }

        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
```

I'm getting the following error:
**No visible @interface for 'StoryService' declares the selector 'getStoryDetailWith:success:failure:'**.
Then, after looking, I figured it was due to the SWIFT function having "inout", which apparenly is not compatible with Objective C. I tried adding `UnsafeMutablePointer<Anyhashble>`, but it doesn't work either.

Can anybody help me out solving this, please? I'm really stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Better to refactor away from using `inout` parameters;

Comment: Add `@objc` qualifier if you want it exposed to Objective-C. When you do that, it will warn you where you use types that cannot be represented in Objective-C (like the `inout`).

Comment: If you use `NSMutableDictionary`, that is a reference type (which allows the called method to mutate it). But as a general principle, it’s better to retire this `inout` behavior...

Comment: Yes, I already tried adding @objc (but forgot to add to the post), and that's when I noticed that "inout" is not compatible and when I started looking around for a solution. I guess the only solution so far then is to completely erase "inout" from my code

Comment: So I erased it, and it seems like it's giving no more problems and the app is working good. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

After the suggestions of two users ([Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) and [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob)), I finally decided to just erase the "inout" behaviour, and it didn't give any problem.